# interaction.response.channel.send problem

Tags: discord, discord.py, pycord

```
async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Modal Results")
    embed.add_field(name="test", value=self.children[0].value)
    embed.add_field(name="test", value=self.children[1].value)
    channel = client.get_channel(1201684034531368994)
    await interaction.response.channel.send(embed)

    await interaction.response.channel.send(embed)
```

i dont have any idea to fix this line
can help me

Comment: put `embed=embed` in the response

Comment: Also see [mre] and include what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of your code:

```py
async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Modal Results")
    embed.add_field(name="test", value=self.children[0].value)
    embed.add_field(name="test", value=self.children[1].value)
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(1201684034531368994) # Changed get_channel to fetch_channel and added 'await' (I personally prefer fetch)channel
    await channel.send(embed = embed) #channel already has attribute "send"

    await channel.send(embed = embed) # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Explanation:

You already got the channel object, so now you can just send a message through the channel object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I edit, hope it can help you

```py
async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Modal Results")
    embed.add_field(name="test", value=self.children[0].value)
    embed.add_field(name="test", value=self.children[1].value)
    channel = client.get_channel(1201684034531368994)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    #You need to send at least a response for the interaction
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

You may also need to read the doc of pycord, here is the link
https://docs.pycord.dev/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).